# Generate event handlers in code behind when copying XAML file

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

I've replaced XAML with a XAML file that already contains event handlers. Usually, when you define event handlers, the functions are automatically created in code behind file. This is not the case if you copy paste the XAML.

Is there a quick way to define all the functions that correspond event handlers in XAML? I am using Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is *no* unfortunately. I have run into similar situations. What I generally do to work around this is to either

1. Right click and copy the control/XAML file and immediately paste getting a `...copy` file. I rename to the new name and then by hand change the name in the code behind and the namespace name reference in the XAML portion.
2. -Or- create a new control and copy the XAML controls to the XAML design and the code behind methods into the new control's scope.